# How to ask that another's question be taken off of 'hold' so I can contribute another answer?

Tags: discussion

The question [Does it matter if i put a resistor in backwards?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/231435/102305) is currently on hold:

> "put on hold as unclear what you're asking..."

I realize some SE functions have limited, fixed vocabulary, so maybe it's on hold for a slightly different reason. But it looks to me like the question is asking a straightforward question that the comments suggest is perfectly clear to many people.

So far the answers are straightforward - electrically; no, but for circuit board inspection and validation purposes - possibly.

I'd like to add another answer in good faith and I feel it can contribute. I've left [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231435/does-it-matter-if-i-put-a-resistor-in-backwards#comment503027_231435) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/231435/does-it-matter-if-i-put-a-resistor-in-backwards#comment503030_231435) comment asking that the hold be lifted so that I can add my answer, but I am not sure if this is the best way to make such a request, or if it's even *allowed* to make such a request.

Can I have some 'best-practices' guidance how best to *ask that another's question be taken off of 'hold' so I can contribute another answer*?

Comment: You can edit the question, and then nominate (or flag, depending on your rep) it for reopening. This question has already been nominated to re-open, so you just need to wait for it to get a couple more reopen votes.

Comment: Thanks @ThePhoton, I'm new to electronics SE and - to me at least - each community's SE has it's own unique... um... user experience. I'll wait and see if someone who's more comfortable editing here comes forth.

Comment: Mere nomination for reopening will not bring it immediately to a moderator's attention -- it just puts it into the community-review queue for reopens. On the other hand, a flag will notify a moderator directly. The moderator may or may not reopen it immediately -- he may choose to let the community reviewers deal with it.

Comment: I notice the question got re-opened.  You can now add your answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop thanks! Now I feel like I'm under the microscope - was partly hoping it wouldn't be!

Comment: You are always under the microscope whenever you write anything here.  The only difference is that this time it's obvious to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is on hold since it's asking for our opinion what the OP can do.  We have no way of knowing the OP's capabilities, nor is that about electrical engineering.  This question is just as bad as the *"Does anyone know ..."* type of questions we get here occasionally.

If he instead had asked whether installing a resistor backwards matters electrically, then that would be extremely naïve but valid question.

You may say that interpreting the former as the latter should be understood.  Maybe, but it's still annoying when people don't ask what they really want to know.  Attention to detail matters in engineering, so sloppiness with language isn't tolerated, just like other types of sloppiness.  Stop and actually *think* about the words you are using instead of blindly writing canned phrases.

Comment: I have asked a best-practices question about how to request a question be taken off of hold. You seem to be answering a different question than I am asking. But I *understand exactly what you are saying* nonetheless. Why not allow for the fact that we all understand that *particular* question similarly?

Comment: @uho: It should be obvious that a question that is rightly on hold should stay on hold and therefore one shouldn't ask to take it off hold.

Comment: Thanks, how do I determine the difference between merely on hold and rightly on hold? Can't a question be wrongly on hold, or debatably on hold as well?

Comment: @uho: Eh, if it's on hold, there's probably a reason.  This site isn't a game to see how crappy a question you can get away with.  If your question got put on hold, then at least 5 users or a mod thought it didn't belong here.  Even if they're wrong, you clearly cut it too close and deserve the tarring and feathering.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Now that I think more about it and continue to look around here, electronics SE sees quite a hefty flux of questions from around the globe and a wide range of experience levels, and I can see the importance of keeping a tight rein on clarity, accuracy and unambiguity (which apparently is a real word).